# Add attribute for NSAttributedString with range

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, nsattributedstring

If the line for which you want to add the attribute is at the beginning of the line, then the attribute is applied to the entire line. And if it is in another place, it works correctly.

**Code:**

```
- (void)applyStyleLinkWithRange:(NSRange)range andAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
     if (NSLocationInRange(range.location + range.length, NSMakeRange(0, [self.attributedString length]))) {
         NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [self.attributedString mutableCopy];
         for (NSString *key in _activeLinkAttributes) {
             [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:key range:range];
         }
         for (NSString *key in _inactiveLinkAttributes) {
             [mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:key range:range];
         }
         [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:attributes range: range];
         self.attributedString = [mutableAttributedString copy];
         mutableAttributedString = nil;
     }}
```

**Number is at the beginning of the line:**

[image: Number is at the beginning of the line]

**Number is at the other place:**

[image: Number is at the other place]

How i can fix this?

Comment: Is that a phone number? You may want to look into `NSDataDetector`.

Comment: @Koen, This a phone number. I get range with NSDataDetector and range correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you be more specific about the desired end result?